# Doctrine - How do you ask WHERE cond1 AND ( cond2 OR cond3)

Tags: sql, symfony1, doctrine

While using Doctrine in a Symfony project I've come into the situation where I need to apply a condition and then one of two following conditions (which both happen to be sub-queries).  I know of the andWhere() and orWhere() functions, but am having trouble using these to generate things like:
  WHERE cond1 AND ( cond2 OR cond3)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049617/complex-where-clauses-using-the-php-doctrine-orm allowed me to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this whith DQL:

```
$models = Doctrine::getTable('ModelName')
    ->findByDql(
        'field_one = ? AND (field_two = ? OR field_three = ?)',
        array('cond_1','cond_2', 'cond_3')
    );
```

So $models will be a Doctrine_Collection with all found elements.

Answer (score 0):

for the cond2 OR cond3 use wherein

where cond1 and wherein cond2 or wherein cond3

hopefully this gets you started

Comment: This seems to help with the subquery part, but doesn't seem to aid in adding the hierarchy to my AND / OR opperators, right?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of this tool but shouldn't something like

```
... where cond1 andWhere (cond2 orWhere cond3)
```

work? Or whatever the actual syntax is. Feel free to tell me if I'm wrong and I'll delete it and slunk off in a corner ;)